# Module calling sub procedures not working?

Tags: excel, vba

EDIT: I have tried putting a break right after it brings in the google data. It works if I run  both subs separately, but it doesn't work in tandem when I try to call them both at same time

I am trying to run a call module in VBA to get google from data and then format some things in the excel template the data is being moved to.

[image]

I have the two subs in module 2.

```
Sub QueryGoogleSheets()
      Dim qt As QueryTable
      Dim url As String, key As String, gid As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")

 
      key = "key"
      gid = "111111111"
      url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?tqx=out:html&key=" & key _
      & "&gid=" & gid
 
      Set qt = ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & url, Destination:=ws.Range("A5"))
 
      With qt
          .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
          .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
          .Refresh
      End With
  End Sub
Sub Validation_formatting()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, Agent As Range, Status As Range, Parcel_ID As Range
    Dim lrow As Long
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master") 'this would be a better method
    lrow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count 'last row in column C
    Set Parcel_ID = ws.Range("A5:A" & lrow)
    Set Agent = ws.Range("M5:M" & lrow) 'populate the rng variable with range you want
    Set Status = ws.Range("N5:N" & lrow)
    
        ws.Rows(5).Delete
        
        With Parcel_ID
            .NumberFormat = "0"
        End With
        
        With Agent.Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:="Mike,William,Kevin,Dan"
        End With
        With Status.Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:="Passed to Agent,Outreach,Negotiating,Denied,Signed"
        
        End With
        
        ws.Columns("B:D").ColumnWidth = 32.58
        ws.Columns("E:Q").autofit
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Metrics").UsedRange.Rows.autofit
End Sub
```

So now I just want to run both of these by creating a new module and calling the two sub procedures:

```
Sub Calls

    call QueryGoogleSheets
    call Validation_formatting
end sub
```

but it doesn't work? Any ideas on how to troubleshoot?

Comment: Try changing the refresh line to: `.Refresh backgroundquery:=false`

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a useful description of what actually happens when you run your code.  There are many ways code can fail, so you need to be a little more specific here.

Comment: @IBas - that's not correct.  You don't need to include the module name.  Did you try it out?

Comment: @TimWilliams I specified in the edit up above. If I run the call.... and call.... module, the data from google does not get brought in. When I run the two subs individually (google table query and then formatting) they work as expected.

Comment: Likely Rory's suggestion may fix things.  It's possible you're calling `Validation_formatting` before the query has completed, because excel can run a query in the background.

Comment: Apologies, @TimWilliams is correct, you don't need to add the declaration of the module, unless there are multiple modules that declare a sub/function with the same name (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2804346/22966032).